# Why isn't the Evil global motion map used in Info mode?

Tags: evil

I'm having a problem where it appears Emacs is not looking at keybindings set in my `evil-motion-state-map`.

Below is my entire `init.el`. I start with an empty `.emacs.d` directory and only install `evil`.

```
;; The following line is a workaround for Emacs 26.2.
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")

(package-initialize)
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))

(setq package-selected-packages
      '(evil))

;;; theme config
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 160)

(defun lookup-spc-tab ()
  "For debugging."
  (interactive)
  (message "SPC TAB binding for motion and normal states: %s %s"
       (lookup-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "SPC TAB"))
       (lookup-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC TAB"))))

;;; evil config
(evil-mode 1)
(lookup-spc-tab)
(evil-define-key 'motion 'global
  (kbd "SPC") (make-sparse-keymap)
  (kbd "SPC TAB") #'switch-to-buffer)
(evil-define-key 'motion Info-mode-map
  (kbd "SPC") (make-sparse-keymap)
  (kbd "SPC SPC") #'Info-scroll-up)
(lookup-spc-tab)
```

When I start Emacs the following is printed in the `*Messages*`, which leads me to believe that `SPC TAB` was set in `evil-motion-state-map`. The following messages come from my debugging function `lookup-spc-tab` and appear in the `*Messages*`.

```
SPC TAB binding for motion and normal states: 1 1
SPC TAB binding for motion and normal states: switch-to-buffer 1
```

Now for my question:

In every mode I've tried (Fundamental, Emacs-Lisp, Message), in both motion and normal state, `SPC SPC` is undefined and `SPC TAB` is `switch-to-buffer`; this is all to be expected.

The exception is Info mode. When I use Info mode, in both motion and normal state, `SPC SPC` is `Info-scroll-up` (expected), but `SPC TAB` is undefined. What is is about Info mode that overrides `SPC TAB`? `SPC TAB` works in every other mode!

However, if I do:

```
...
(evil-define-key 'normal 'global
  (kbd "SPC") (make-sparse-keymap)
  (kbd "SPC TAB") #'switch-to-buffer)
(evil-define-key 'normal Info-mode-map
  (kbd "SPC") (make-sparse-keymap)
  (kbd "SPC SPC") #'Info-scroll-up)
...
```

That is, if I change my config to modify normal states instead of motion states, then everything works (in normal state) in every mode, even Info mode. Specifically, `SPC TAB` is defined in every mode, including Info mode, and `SPC SPC` is defined only in Info mode. All as expected.

So, again, my question is, what is it about `evil-motion-state-map` that gets overridden in Info mode only? And why does only motion state get overridden but not normal state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the emacs wiki for evil there is a section about this: [Managing keymaps > Overriding and intercept keymaps](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil#toc9):

> **Overriding and intercept keymaps**
>
> There are Emacs modes that provide their own single letter key bindings, independent of Evil. BufferMenu, Ediff, and Edebug are a few examples. By default, Evil allows these modes’ keymaps to override Evil’s. To change this behavior, customize the evil-overriding-maps and evil-intercept-maps variables. (...)

The default value of `evil-overriding-maps` includes `(Info-mode-map . motion)`. This means that by default that mode keymaps overrides the evil one in motion state.